# How I can use std::bind to bind class member function as function pointer?

Tags: c++11

I have Base and Dervided classes. In the Base class I have a typedef for specific function pointer (I think this is function pointer, im not sure):

`typedef void (responseHandler)(BaseClass* instance,int resultCode, char* resultString);`

And in the same base class I have several functions which accepts this typedef:

`unsigned sendDescribeCommand(responseHandler* responseHandler, Authenticator* authenticator = NULL);`

In my custom derived class from this Base class I have my response handler function, like this:

`void continueAfterDESCRIBE(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString);`

How I can use this method as input for `sendDescribeCommand`? 
I tried this: 
`DerivedClass->sendDescribeCommand(DerivedCLass->continueAfterDescribe, MyAuth)`, but this did not build with error: 
"error C3867: 'DerivedClass::continueAfterDESCRIBE': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

I also tried to use `std::bind`:

`auto responseCallback = std::bind(&DerivedClass::continueAfterDESCRIBE, DerivedClassInstance);
    DerivedClass->sendDescribeCommand(responseCallback, ourAuthenticator);`

It also give me an error: no suitable conversion from std::bind to my response handler.

I know there is a way to make my method static, but Im curious if there is another way?

Comment: That is not a function pointer typedef. It's missing an asterisk. `typedef void(*responseHandler)(BaseClass*, resultCode, char*);` is a typedef for a function pointer.

If you want to get a generic callable, you may want to consider using a `std::function` in the interface for `sendDescribeCommand` instead so that you can use the type-erasure present in `std::function` to pass a variety of callable types that satisfy the return type and arguments.

Comment: Use the `instance` parameter to get back to the `DerivedClass`.